# Regular expression for non negative integers including 0

Tags: regex

How can I represent non negative integers including 0 and no integer, except 0 should start by a 0 using regular expression?
Example:

```
111 (true)|
0   (true)|
013 (false)|
120 (true)|
```

The regex I tried:

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]?)$
```

This is how it's represented if 0 isn't included.

Comment: Please make a title for the question that briefly describes issue. Put question in the question's body, also add all relevant code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/R5y6Ht/2)):

```
^(?!0\d+)\d+
```

Which evaluates:

```
111  - True
0    - True
013  - False 
120  - True
```

Comment: Just a minor note, you can omit the plus after the digit in the lookahead, as it does not matter if there are 1 or more `^(?!0\d)\d+`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the quantifier from `?` (which matches 0 or 1 times) to `*` which matches zero or more times.

Now the pattern matches either a single `0` or a digit that starts with 1-9 followed by optional digits 0-9.

```
^(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MZuVc0/1)

Or if a non capture group is not supported

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$
```